# Two Linear Layouts display

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have two lenear layouts in my xml & first has layout height & width as a fill_parent.
Now on below part i want to display second layout also with first layout as it is. is it possible ?
My xml code is as following

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#e0ffff" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100px"
                android:layout_height="100px"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                android:src="@drawable/Catlog" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100px"
                android:layout_height="100px"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                android:src="@drawable/Mycatlog" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100px"
                android:layout_height="100px"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                android:src="@drawable/Events" >
            </ImageView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100px"
                android:layout_height="100px"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                android:src="@drawable/Lerningprofiles" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100px"
                android:layout_height="100px"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                android:src="@drawable/Profile" >
            </ImageView>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#0F304C"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightsum="0.05" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:src="@drawable/Profile" >
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You've to be a bit more specific. Please post your XML layout code..

Comment: fill_Parent means the first layout itself will occupy the whole space on the screen and the second layout will never appear on screen.considering that they are oriented vertically.Still copy your xml here and may be then we can suggest better.

Comment: I have added the code plz chek it

Answer (score 0):

No,Instead you can use a relative layout as  parent layout and then put a linear layout as its child..I think this can give the view you want..because android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" has no effect unless the LinearLayout is nested inside a RelativeLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
...
<LinearLayout 
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand the reason for you having a seperate LinearLayout for displaying the final ImageView.

The same can be displayed by just adding a 3rd  like below:

```
<TableRow >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100px"
                android:layout_height="100px"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                android:background="#0F304C"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
            </ImageView>

        </TableRow>
```

A few recommendations though is that:

1. Never use px values directly in your layouts.
2. Try using the [layoutopt](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/layoutopt.html) command line tool for all your layouts
   for better performance and optimized layouts.

Comment: because i want it to be bottom & i dont want to giv hard code value

Comment: What is the issue if you give the tablerow even then the ImageView inside it will appear at the bottom.